# Rounding decimals to two decimal places in telerik reporting

Tags: telerik, telerik-reporting

Is there anyway to round number similar to 1.66667 up to two decimal places like 1.67 in telerik reporting. I know that they have an build in function called `Round(number)`. But it only round into integer value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try format function like

```
    =Format("{0:0.00}", 1,6667)
```

Answer (score 0):

try to bind data as below sample

```
var apiOutput = new
                {
                    invoceRpt = invoceRpt.Select(a => new
                    {

                        UnitPrice = String.Format("{0:0,0.00}", Convert.ToDecimal(a.UnitPrice)),                     

                    })
                };
  this.DataSource = apiOutput.invoceRpt;
```